# How to solve over-determined linear system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, matlab

at the moment I am working on an application where I have to solve some systems of linear equations during the whole algorithm.

Because the programming-language I have to use is something related to Fortran77 (which uses 'float' as number-format) and sometimes the Matrices are badly scaled, I choose this [gaussian-elimination-with-pivoting-script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45415-gaussian-elimination-with-pivoting-method) and adapted it for my programming-language. This works pretty well.

Now I have the problem that sometimes the equation-system is over-determined and this couldn't be handled by the script I mentionned before.

Does anyone know if there is somewhere an efficient script to solve determined systems as well as over-determined systems which I can use (e.g. with QR-decomposition [determined] and least-squares [over-determined])?

Here are 2 examples of typical matrices that can occur (A is the coefficient-matrix and b the disturbing-vector):

[the determined one]

```
 A = [ 3.91126953294906e-13  0.000290530407713016    0.118719995662381      0.999861140092325;
      -7.47034897265332e-13 -0.000158174186504138   -0.0169130360585405   -9.28246904902663e-06;
       1.42680307002891e-12  8.61151625166872e-05  0.00240945754016845   8.61761980650444e-11;
      -2.72512972030656e-12 -4.68838903437727e-05   -0.000343255085472549 -8.00038984641107e-16 ]

b = [ -0.000272415115940619; -9.83039417624391e-07;  1.42984225458907e-07;  3.29280620635692e-09 ]
```

(in Matlab i get: rank(A) = 4 and rank([A, b]) = 4 $\rightarrow$ one solution exists)

[the over-determined one]

```
A = [ 9.71932695068104e-21  1.95542531016539e-06  0.0319594622483047    0.999775498752868;
     -7.90937295921570e-21 -4.53931579859449e-07 -0.00194341016115096  -3.96425686254142e-06;
      6.43647249705794e-21  1.05375479248690e-07  0.000118176051434193  1.57188613761892e-11;
     -5.23785873026922e-21 -2.44618178588262e-08 -7.18612026002067e-06 -6.23275967050862e-17 ]

b = [ 4.42616984297712e-05; -1.36475494887893e-06;  9.48249135038941e-08;  3.66966454607991e-09 ]
```

(in Matlab this leads to rank(A) = 3 and rank([A, b]) = 4 $\rightarrow$ over-determined

So ... now I am looking for a code-snippet or something like this which can find solutions for both systems. I don't know if there exist one or which method is the best. Is it a QR-decomposition (with least squares) ...

I hope that somebody has a little hint for me or can help me ... that would be great. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since you already have Matlab, why don't you just use Matlab to solve it?

Comment: @KittyL the problem is that I have to use the calculation routine in a 'external' project that is written in something related to 'Fortran77' and doesn't has the functionality of Matlab. - I'd be happy if I could use Matlab but that's unfortunately not possible.

Comment: You know netlib.org and that you can find f77 compatible LAPACK sources there?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html

Comment: What about using SVD decomposition, which is related to least squares in case of over-determination ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Say that you have $n$ nonlinear equations to solve for $m$ variables $$f_i=f_i(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)=0$$ What you can do is to minimize $$\Phi(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2$$ Now, the Jacobian of $\Phi$ gives you as many equations as variables.

Gauss-Newton method is a good candidate, provided "reasonable" starting values (except if the $f_i$ are just linear functions; in such a case, the solution is direct).

As you mentionned, the problem is very similar to least-square fit.

Comment: thank you for your answer. (Yes, my equation system is always linear and always 4 x 4) - Ii see what you mean. If I'm right, with this method I can solve determined as well as over-determined equation systems? But is this method also "numerically stable"? Do there exist some samples of an implementation of this method?

Comment: If linear, the problem is simple and the solution immediate using matrix. The equations given by the Jacobian are linear. So, end of the story. Treat the problem as multilinear regression and you are done.

Comment: I see ... so that means that this works for over-determined as well as determined systems of linear-equations? Is there somewhere a code snippet?

Comment: This works for any kind of functions (linear, nolinear,..). For linear equations, the solution is immediate if you look at the so-called normal equations (there are the derivatives of $\Phi$).